# Will NTFS-3G and FUSE work out of the box if I upgrade from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, upgrade, ntfs, filesystem

On Snow Leopard I already have NTFS-3G (2010.10.2) and FUSE (MacFUSE Framework 2.2.1). I managed to install them and it works like a charm.

If I upgrade to Mountain Lion, does the operating system pick it up or I have to do it again from the scratch?

Comment: I checked and I have MacFuse Framework ver. 2.2.1 and NTF-3g 2010.10.2

Answer (score 2):

Following that major upgrade of the operating system, you may find that some features of your product combination (NTFS-3G for Mac OS X, with a 2.2.1 version of the MacFUSE framework) are:

- usable, but unreliable, with a risk of kernel panics.

## Recommendation

Install [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com) 2.4.2 or greater, with its MacFUSE compatibility layer:

- before or soon after the upgrade of the operating system
- certainly before you attempt to use NTFS-3G or any other software title that requires MacFUSE.

### Background

Maintenance of MacFUSE, in the Google Code area, ceased in 2009.

Successors to MacFUSE include FUSE for OS X, also known as OSXFUSE. The first version with experimental support for OS X 10.8 was [2.4.0](http://osxfuse.github.com/2012/05/28/OSXFUSE-2.4.0.html) (2012-05).

In my experience with OSXFUSE 2.3.8 and greater on multiple builds of Mountain Lion:

- OSXFUSE 2.4.2 should be good for the vast majority of use cases with released Build 12A269 of the operating system
- a delay-related alert may appear whenever an NTFS volume is mounted with NTFS-3G (2010.10.2) – this alert, not specific to Mountain Lion, may be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

So at the end I upgraded to Mountain Lion, but for the moment I am still keeping with my versions of free MacFuse and NTFS-3g.

I reinstalled them after upgrade and applied the patch for 15 seconds error found on this blog

http://blog.nolar.info/ntfs-3g-in-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-with-read-write-support/

For now no r/w problems on my bootcamp partition but if you can suggest that I do a specific test to see if it is reliable enough, you are more than welcomed.

Nevertheless, if I encounter problems in the future I will pass to OSXFUSE.

Cheers

Comment: If this is your answer, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote buttons. Thank you!